# Elasticsearch terms look up using query

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am using the bool filter for doing cardinality as well as value count aggregation. My term filter has almost 2000 terms and so it is taking a lot of time to load. Also for me it is not possible to test it manually by specifying the filter terms.

I just read about 'Terms Lookup' feature. Is there any possibility that I can specify an array or another query in the terms lookup, so I an avoid fetching up the terms first uaing PHP and then using them in the aggregation query.

My PHP code for the above metioned operation is like this :

```
$reportParams['body']['query'] = array(
    "filtered" => array(
        "filter" => array(
            "bool" => array(
                "must" => array(
                    "range" => array(
                        "time" => array(
                            "gt" => $start,
                            "lt" => $end
                        )
                    )
                ),
                "should" =>$termFilter
            )
        )
    )
    );

$reportParams['body']['aggs'] = array(
"distinct_user_count" => array(
    "cardinality" => array(
        "field" => $details->agg_field
    )
),
"daily_event_count" => array(
    "value_count" => array(
        "field" => $details->agg_field
    )
)
);
```

and the termsFilter is an array like this :

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [term] => Array
                (
                    [andi] => 84cc04c6059fb490
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [term] => Array
                (
                    [andi] => af9cbd253100f2c7
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [term] => Array
                (
                    [andi] => c1a3fcf0fefe7107
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [term] => Array
                (
                    [andi] => b3a630084347fb2f
                )

        )
```

Comment: Can you show how `$termFilter` looks like? Also how many different values do you have for that field approximately?

Comment: The upper limit is 2000 and all are unique. I will update the question with termsfilter variable.

Comment: @Val I have updated the question with termsFilter

Comment: Is this really the array you give to the `should` clause or is there something else? Also why are you including all the 2000 terms in your `should` clause? If all you have are those 2000 terms and you want them all, you don't need the `should` clause at all. Last question, what is `$details->agg_field`

Comment: @Val There was a mistake with the terms filter. It is something like this. I am actually searching on a type for the event count for specified users which is done thorugh the "andi" field. The agg_field is also "andi"

Comment: Looks like a redesign is needed here? Terms filter with 2000 terms feels a bit insane.

Comment: no there isn't, i remember there is a ticket of this.